# Root-finding by iterated bisection

Tags: python, error-handling, comparative-review, iteration, numerical-methods

Both of the following code give the same result.  But I'm not sure where should I put the `raise` statement.

```
def bisection(f, start, stop, eps = 1e-5, max_iteration = 100):
  for __ in range(max_iteration):
    half = start + (stop - start)/2
    if abs(f(half)) < eps or half - start < eps:
      return half 
    if f(half) * f(start) > 0:
      start = half
    else:
      stop = half
  else:
    raise ValueError('Cannot find root in the given range')
```

Or

```
def bisection(f, start, stop, eps = 1e-5, max_iteration = 100):
  for __ in range(max_iteration):
    half = start + (stop - start)/2
    if abs(f(half)) < eps or half - start < eps:
      return half 
    if f(half) * f(start) > 0:
      start = half
    else:
      stop = half

  raise ValueError('Cannot find root in the given range')
```

P.S.  I [asked this question Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/32044613/1157100) and someone there suggested to ask it here.

Comment: @Morwenn Python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two versions work exactly the same way, because the end of the loop will only be reached if the `return` is not executed.

However, the `for ... else` construct can be confusing.
Everything else being equal,
it's best to use the simplest technique that is unambiguous,
perfectly clear to everyone, without further questions asked.
So, go with the 2nd version,
no need for the "clever" but potentially confusing `for ... else` construct here.

Answer (score 3):

### Bug

I see no justification for `or half - start < eps`.  With that, you no longer guarantee that the return value is a root of `f`.